# Marker Style Changes when I Change Marker Size

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm using matplotlib 3.3.2 to plot some data points. I'd like to plot two different kinds of data with two different marker styles - one with 'o' and one with 'x'. I'd also like to make the size of the points small, around a marker size of .4-.5. However, when I plot my data for a marker size less than about 1.2, the x markers turn into dots that look a lot like the o markers (but are slightly more diamond shaped). I've tried to set the marker style in several different places to be 'x' for that data, but nothing I've tried has worked. How can I plot small points with different marker styles.

Here's an example of code that produces the unexpected behavior:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple

%matplotlib inline

matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['font.size'] = 8
matplotlib.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 600
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amsmath}']
matplotlib.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 8

x_data = 100 * np.random.rand(100)
o_data = 100 * np.random.rand(100)

xs = np.linspace(0, 100, num = len(x_data))

x_marker, x_size, x_lw = 'x', .5, 1
o_marker, o_size, o_lw = 'o', .5, 1

plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))

plt.loglog(xs, x_data, marker=x_marker, markersize=x_size, linewidth = x_lw, linestyle = 'None')
plt.loglog(xs, o_data, marker=o_marker, markersize=o_size, linewidth = o_lw, linestyle = 'None')

plt.show()
```

Comment: @BigBen plt.scatter(np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100), marker='x', s=1)

Comment: I would raise an issue on the matplotlib github repository. This looks like a bug.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen - I believe one should use `linewidths` here as well. `x` is a non-filled marker IIRC so one has to adjust the marker edges, I'm guessing.

Comment: @BigBen `linewidth` affects the linewidth of the line marking the border of the patches. The way the documentation is written, it should not affect the size of the marker. Now, in this particular case, I think there is a crosstalk between the two. For example, compare: `plt.scatter(np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100), marker='o', s=100, linewidth=0)` with `plt.scatter(np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100), marker='x', s=100, linewidth=0)`, where the second plot has not visible output. That is a bug, not a feature.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen - not a bug IMO, because since `x` only has lines/edges you've effectively made it invisible.

Comment: Your point makes sense from the viewpoint of a matplotlib developer but not from the viewpoint of a user. IMO, if the marker is unfilled, matplotlib should adjust the linewidth if the given size is too small (or at least raise a warning). The reason that OP is seeing diamonds instead of crosses, is that the linewidth is larger than the length of the arms of the crosses. OP has to adjust both, linewidth and size, to get a sensible output: `plt.scatter(np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100), marker='x', s=1, linewidth=0.5)`. There is nothing in the docs that would alert him/her to that.

Comment: atBigBen - I've tried adjusting the linewidths as well in case that had an impact. Unfortunately, it did not.@PaulBroderson adjusting linewidth and size for the desired size (s~.5) is still failing. Because of the specifics of the data I'm plotting, I cannot increase the size very much, which would *easily* fix this, of course.

Comment: @BigBen example added to parent.

Comment: Should be using `markeredgewidth` instead of `linewidth`. Try playing around with larger sizes and smaller widths.

Comment: I can't really increase the size more than .5 or so or else the real figure is very difficult to read. For a size of .5, I still get the same plotting problem with small markeredgewidth. Relatively small values of edge width wiped out the x_data entirely!